# How do I rename a module in Sahana Eden?

Tags: python, web2py, web2py-modules

I have this Requests module. I wish to rename it to Requisitions. Can someone please confirm how to change name of a module?

In views/index.html file the title is coming from =T("title") but i am unsure where is this title coming from.

Here's the code to html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W4C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="{{=T.accepted_language or "en"}}">{{# class="no-js" needed for modernizr }}
<head>{{theme=response.s3.theme}}
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
{{# Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame }}
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

**<title>{{try:}}{{=title}}{{except:}}{{=response.title or settings.get_system_name_short()}}{{pass}}</title>**


{{if response.refresh:}}{{=XML(response.refresh)}}{{pass}}
{{# http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/meta.name.html }}
<meta name="application-name" content="{{=appname}}" />
{{# Set your site up with Google: http://google.com/webmasters }}
{{# <meta name="google-site-verification" content="" /> }}
{{a="""<!--  Mobile Viewport Fix
 j.mp/mobileviewport & davidbcalhoun.com/2010/viewport-metatag
 device-width: Occupy full width of the screen in its current orientation
 initial-scale = 1.0 retains dimensions instead of zooming out if page height > device height
 maximum-scale = 1.0 retains dimensions instead of zooming in if page width < device width
--> """}}
```

[Requests Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pacST.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please help us by including the code relevant to your issue. This helps us determine how to answer your issue. Thanks!

Comment: added a portion of code with title mentioned in ** that is required to be understood.

Comment: I think `=title` is not displaying the title, its coming from `except` block. In `models/menu.py`, `response.title` is defined.